# extract substring using pl sql

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a table T1 with below data

```
Sno  Ns_NAME       Mode    stat
1    AF_rtf_Nd_1   Manual  2
2    AF_rtf_Nd_2   Manual  3
3    AF_rtf_Nd_2i  Manual  2
4    AF_rtf_Nd_3   Auto    2
5    AF_rtf_Nd_3i  Auto    3
```

I need to perform below,

check if it is manual, fetch from Ns_NAME upto last "_" and check for duplicates. In this case there is 1 duplicate. Obtain average  stat [(2+3)/2] of those two rows and pump into another table T2.

**Output:**

T2

```
    AF_rtf_Nd      Manual  2.5
```

I tried using substr function and used etract . But it is not fetching the correct result.

Comment: What is the logic behind choosing `1` as the output `Sno` ?  Can you show us an extended sample `T1` with more `Manual` and `Auto` records?

Comment: Now that you changed your sample data, the lines 1, 2, and 3 start with 'AF_rtf_Nd', so the avarage should be (2+3+2)/3 = 2.33, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to look at 'Manual' records only, use a `WHERE` clause. Then aggregate over the substring. You get the substring with `INSTR` plus `SUBSTR` or with `REGEX_REPLACE`. Then only keep duplicates by using `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`.

```
insert into t2
select
  min(sno),
  regexp_replace(ns_name, '_[^_]*$', ''),
  'Manual',
  avg(stat)
from t1
where mode = 'Manual'
group by regexp_replace(ns_name, '_[^_]*$', '') 
having count(*) > 1;
```

The equivalent to the `REGEXP_REPLACE` with `INSTR` and `SUBSTR` is

```
substr(ns_name, 1, instr(ns_name, '_', -1) - 1)
```

(Only difference is when there is no '_' in the string at all.)

Comment: This will check only for 'Manual'. If there is any duplicate for 'Auto' or any other mode, it will not work.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. You said "check if it is manual". Now you say "This will check only for 'Manual'". Well, yes, and this is what it's supposed to do. What else?

Comment: Thanks. This does solve the issue. I just extended the logic to perform groupby on the "mode" column.